# directshow problem

Tags: c#, directshow

I'm using DirectShow.net to capture images from a webCame,after searching the web I got this code and it works fine:

to see the original full code kindly follow the link below

```
 bool SetupGraph()
        {
            int hr;
            try
            {
                hr = capGraph.SetFiltergraph(graphBuilder);
                if (hr < 0)
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(capFilter, "Ds.NET Video Capture Device");
                if (hr < 0)
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                DsUtils.ShowCapPinDialog(capGraph, capFilter, this.Handle);

                AMMediaType media = new AMMediaType();
                media.majorType = MediaType.Video;
                media.subType = MediaSubType.RGB24;
                media.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;        // ???
                hr = sampGrabber.SetMediaType(media);
                if (hr < 0)
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber");
                if (hr < 0)
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                Guid cat = PinCategory.Preview;
                Guid med = MediaType.Video;
                hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref cat, ref med, capFilter, null, null); // baseGrabFlt 
                if (hr < 0)
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                cat = PinCategory.Capture;
                med = MediaType.Video;
                hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref cat, ref med, capFilter, null, baseGrabFlt); // baseGrabFlt 
                if (hr < 0)
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                media = new AMMediaType();
                hr = sampGrabber.GetConnectedMediaType(media);
                if (hr < 0)
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
                if ((media.formatType != FormatType.VideoInfo) || (media.formatPtr == IntPtr.Zero))
                    throw new NotSupportedException("صيغه غير معروفه");

                videoInfoHeader = (VideoInfoHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(media.formatPtr, typeof(VideoInfoHeader));
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(media.formatPtr); media.formatPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

                hr = sampGrabber.SetBufferSamples(false);
                if (hr == 0)
                    hr = sampGrabber.SetOneShot(false);
                if (hr == 0)
                    hr = sampGrabber.SetCallback(null, 0);
                if (hr < 0)
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Could not setup graph\r\n" + ee.Message, "DirectShow.NET", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

my problem is when I call this form from another form for a second time it gives me this error: `"Value does not fall within the expected range"` when the compiler comes to this section:
`hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref cat, ref med, capFilter, null, null);`

actually i discovered that the problem disappear when I unplug the web-came physically and plug it again, so I concluded that i need to unplug it using code
so please if u know tell me how to do it or if u have any better idea please tell me

you can access the original code on 
http://www.codeproject.com/script/Content/ViewAssociatedFile.aspx?rzp=%2FKB%2Fdotnet%2FROTEsys%2Frotesys_src.zip&zep=Tracking.cs&obid=9401&obtid=2&ovid=1[^]

thank you for ur time and patience

Answer (score 1):

Only one graph for a single video source can be running at a time, think of it as a pipeline with a single source.

If you want to start another graph, you will have to stop the first one first - your code currently does that in  `CloseInterfaces();` - so you should be fine if you call that before building up the second graph.

Comment: thank you for ur fast response but I do call CloseInterfaces(); and I still get the error, the value that returns from :hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref cat, ref med, capFilter, null, null); is -2147024809

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably when you are closing the interfaces, you have to use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` in all your interfaces of DirectShow, and also, you have to use the method `RemoveFilter` of your `IGraphBuilder` to relase your used capture filter, if you don't do so the graph builder won't be released.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the CloseInterfases() method, add the following lines:

```
if (graphBuilder != null)
{
    graphBuilder.RemoveFilter(capFilter);
}
baseGrabFlt = null;
```

Comment: Some description of what the code does and why it helps would be good.